# Remove duplicated lines based on field and length

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I need remove duplicated lines based on field between parenthesis (Ex: (265394673718132736)) but removing the shorter line.

Example:

```
SERVER: 1 - (265394673718132736) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP1']
SERVER: 2 - (284906813495967745) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP1']
SERVER: 3 - (184387362225258496) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP2']
SERVER: 4 - (118642771161645056) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP1', 'SAR']
SERVER: 4 - (118642771161645056) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP1']
SERVER: 5 - (234329090943877122) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP4', 'SAR']
SERVER: 5 - (234329090943877122) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP4', 'SAR', 'NO']
SERVER: 6 - (287039745190658069) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP6']
SERVER: 7 - (280378736145072130) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP3']
```

Desidered result:

```
SERVER: 1 - (265394673718132736) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP1']
SERVER: 2 - (284906813495967745) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP1']
SERVER: 3 - (184387362225258496) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP2']
SERVER: 4 - (118642771161645056) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP1', 'SAR']
SERVER: 5 - (234329090943877122) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP4', 'SAR', 'NO']
SERVER: 6 - (287039745190658069) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP6']
SERVER: 7 - (280378736145072130) - NO - ['OK', 'GROUP3']
```

EDIT:

Tried with:

```
cat test | cut -f1 -d ":" --complement | sort -u -t'-' -k2,2
```

But I need remove the shorter line, not random.

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? Do you stuck on any line of your code?

Comment: What have you done so far? I don't see any code. It looks like you want us to write your code for you. Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Edited, I was trying cut and sort... but it's not working because it's random and can't get it working by length,

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{a[$4]=length(a[$4])<length?$0:a[$4]}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' file
```

does the job.

Note that, the order of lines in output is not preserved.